# Git Pushing Error

Tags: git

I am using a centralized git workflow where there is a central repo on a Windows server and we have working directories on development machines.  Everything was going fine until I all of the sudden started getting errors when pushing to the remote repo.  This is the error:

```
remote: fatal: failed to write object
fatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' write error: Broken Pipe
error: failed to push some refs to 'my_central_repo'
```

I can't figure out what happened but I need to push my project to the central repo, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have tried it about 100 times lol. I restarted my machine and everything. Unfortunately I don't believe it is that simple.

Comment: Do you manage git server ? Do you have enough disk space ? Correct file/directory permission ?

Comment: Did You try this? http://blog.lukebennett.com/2011/07/25/git-broken-pipe-error-when-pushing-to-a-repository/

Answer (score 9):

This may also be due to owner permissions issue on your remote git repo directory. It also happens when creating the directory as root.

If you do

```
# ls -al <repo-name>.git
```

and see

```
drwxr-xr-x .. .. root root .. .. <repo-name>.git
```

then that may the the source of the issue, you are trying to push to the repo with a non-root account.

Which can be easily resolved by:

```
# chown -R git:git <repo-name>.git ; ls -al
drwxr-xr-x .. .. git git .. .. <repo-name>.git
```

and then enjoy a successful `git push`

Answer (score 5):

While troubleshooting the problem I found [this article](http://blog.lukebennett.com/2011/07/25/git-broken-pipe-error-when-pushing-to-a-repository/) explaining the root cause but in my case it was slow network that was causing this problem. Once I moved to the faster network push went through. May be something has to do with timeout.

Answer (score 1):

In my case was truing to push first commit to remote bitbucket repository. The error appeared after cmd:

```
git push -u origin master
```

The problem got resolved by removing the "-u" flag

Answer (score 0):

I am still trying to figure out the root cause, but as suspected it was a permissions related error. When I mapped the network drive to the directory where my central repo exists using the Admin account for my GitServer it resolved the issue.

The strange thing is, I was previously pushing to my GitServer repo not problem with the network drive mapped with my personal credentials so I am not sure what happened that changed the permissions on my repo for my user. No other users using other central repos experienced this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the remote URL from https to git

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/reponame.git
```

Answer (score -2):

Unless it's a permission problem with the git server (do you have admin rights?), it might be that there are some new pushes since you last pulled. Try:

```
git pull --rebase origin master
git push origin master
```

Comment: I do believe it is permission related but I am not sure hot to resolve it.  Its weird because the user I am logged in as was pushing fine...then all of the sudden I was just no longer able to. How do I ensure I have admin rights?