# Faltal Error on Pushing to a Remote from a VM

Tags: git, push

I'm working on creating central remote Git-Repositories for my dev team. So I created a Fileshare in our network, which we can access with our credential. On this Fileshare I put our bare-clone Git repositories, so we have the remote repositories. When I work on my computer, I can do all the git actions without a problem. But when I work in a Virtual Maschine I can't push my changes into remote repository. I received errors in the screenshot.

Before you look in the error, I just want to explain a bit of my tries:

1. The original try
2. After I google the Error and saw someone said that his local repository was set "read only", I went and checked mine, which also set permission like that. So I changed the permission. In 2. Try I saw the push went a bit further.
3. After a long google again and saw someone said the "package" maybe too big, so I change from "push --all" to "push" as I understand, that I only push the current branch, instead all local changes (?). Anyway the error stays and I'm frustrated, that's why I wrote this post.

[image: Error]

Again: The problem only happens, when I push from a VM, so I think it has something to do with the setting of my VM. Could someone help me? I can't keep copying the local git into my computer, then push into remote, since the folder gets bigger and bigger....

I'm using VMware® Workstation 15 Player (Verion 15.5.7 build-17171714)

Could someone help me?

Thank you and best regards
K.

Edit: Here is the error in codeblock as suggested by Lucidbrot:

```
PS E:LocalRepository> git push --all
Enumerating objects: 134, done.
Counting objects: 100% (134/134), done.
Delta compression using up to 6 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (79/79), done.
remote: error: unable to create temporary file: Invalid argument
remote: fatal: failed to write object
fatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' write error: Broken pipe
error: remote unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
To G:RemoteRepository
 ! [remote rejected] feature -> feature (unpacker error)
 ! [remote rejected] debug-working -> debug-working (unpacker error)
 ! [remote rejected] other-way -> other-way (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to 'G:RemoteRepository'
PS E:LocalRepository> git push --all
Enumerating objects: 134, done.
Counting objects: 100% (134/134), done.
Delta compression using up to 6 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (79/79), done.
remote: error: unable to create temporary file: Invalid argument
remote: fatal: failed to write object
remote: fatal: Unable to read current working directory: Function not implemented
fatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' write error: Broken pipe
error: remote unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
To G:RemoteRepository
 ! [remote rejected] feature -> feature (unpacker error)
 ! [remote rejected] debug-working -> debug-working (unpacker error)
 ! [remote rejected] other-way -> other-way (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to 'G:RemoteRepository'
PS E:LocalRepository> git push
Enumerating objects: 134, done.
Counting objects: 100% (134/134), done.
Delta compression using up to 6 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (79/79), done.
remote: error: file write error: Invalid argument
remote: fatal: unable to write loose object file
remote: fatal: Unable to read current working directory: Function not implemented
fatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' write error: Broken pipe
error: remote unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
To G:RemoteRepository
 ! [remote rejected] feature -> feature (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to 'G:RemoteRepository'
```

The same local repository pushed from my computer:

```
C:CopiedLocalRepository>git status
On branch feature
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/feature' by 7 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean

C:CopiedLocalRepository>git push --all
Enumerating objects: 134, done.
Counting objects: 100% (134/134), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (79/79), done.
Writing objects: 100% (97/97), 154.96 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 97 (delta 63), reused 22 (delta 10), pack-reused 0
```

Comment: Can you push the same changes from your computer? I.e. is the problem the VM or the changes you made in the repo? Because to me the errors read like it should have to do with the remote ... or another idea: maybe the VM uses a very different version of git?

Comment: Btw, Please include the errors as text in code blocks. That way other people with the same issue will find this question more easily

Comment: Some related ideas to check: [this looks like a server issue](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/2428#issuecomment-402714742), [is there enough disk space on the server and VM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36874919/git-pushing-error#comment61317239_36874919), [is the filesystem on the server supporting your filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66241314/git-error-unable-to-commit-specific-file-unable-to-create-temporary-file-inv#comment117132978_66241314)?, and also notice the `Function not implemented` on the remote that sounds very weird to me

Comment: @lucidbrot Hi, thank you for answering. When I copy the local git from my VM to my computer and push. It worked well. It means: Yes, I can push the same changes from my computer. That's also the reason, I think it has nothing to do with the server... I also check many related ideas, but they seems not really related :(

Comment: That's odd... so just to be sure, the fileshare in general is accessible from the VM, right? Does the VM use the same operating system as the other device?

Comment: The message `error: unable to create temporary file: Invalid argument` is coming from the Git process started separately to write *to* the shared bare repository. The "invalid argument" part indicates that the OS is rejecting the attempt with an `EINVAL` error in the C library, so you should investigate as to when and why it might do that.

Comment: The subsequent `fatal: Unable to read current working directory: Function not implemented` is very similar, except it's apparently getting `ENOSYS` here. [This may be related.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58199056/1256452) Also try [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+%22function+not+implemented%22+error).